# O que é um literal?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Nesse [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dzy06xhf.aspx) do site da MSDN diz que um literal é:

> Um literal é um valor que é expresso como si mesmo em vez de como um valor variável ou o resultado de uma expressão, como o número 3 ou a sequência "Alô".

Mesmo assim eu não entendi o que é um literal. No mesmo link tem um exemplo:

```vb
Option Strict On

Public Class Sample
    Public Const MyByte As Byte = 2
End Class
```

Agora minhas dúvidas são:

- O que é um literal?
- Para qual finalidade ele existe?
- Onde tem um literal no exemplo acima?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No exemplo acima o literal é o 2.

O termo literal não é algo do .NET ou mesmo da computação, é um termo matemático básico.

Literal pode ser dito, grosso modo, já que está difícil entender, como **um valor fixo**.

Ele existe para determinar valores. O mais comum é que estes valores sejam números. Muitos desses números podem ter um sufixo indicado o seu tipo, ou podem ter prefixos indicando se a notação é diferente do decimal (hexadecimal, binário e octal são comuns). Outro literal bem comum é o que representa um texto, uma *string* ou mesmo apenas um caractere. `true` e `false` costumam ser literais do tipo booleano.

Algumas linguagens possuem outros literais. Algumas permitem até que se crie um literal, ainda que raro porque dá confusão.

O literal é sempre constante, mas **uma constante não precisa ser representada por um literal**. Muitas pessoas usam o termo constante inadequadamente para o literal. Apesar do literal ser constante ele pode ser atribuído para variáveis, o literal nunca mudará, mas o valor da variável poderá mudar.

Literal é exatamente como está colocado ali, não será manipulado, não cabe interpretação, não é algo representativo, é aquilo e só.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eu: **"Resumindo, é a mesma coisa que uma constante?"** bigown diz: *"O literal é sempre constante"*, jbueno diz: *"Não. Constantes têm valores literais definidos e não podem ter valor mudado durante a execução."*

Comment: Está escrito na resposta que não.

Comment: Editei o comentário.

Comment: Um literal é constante. O que eu quis dizer é que você não declara uma constante por causa de um valor literal.

Answer (score 3):

Um literal é um valor que  é expresso **literalmente** no meio do seu código.

No seu exemplo, **2** é um literal.

```
Public Const MyByte As Byte = 2
```

No exemplo abaixo (em C#), **meu texto** é um literal

```
var algumaString = "meu texto";
```

---

#### Literais não são variáveis, nem constantes

Você pode definir um valor literal para uma variável

```
var texto = "meu texto";
```

para uma constante

```
const string Nome = "João";
```

ou, até mesmo, mostrar um literal numa MessageBox

```
MessageBox.Show("Meu literal");
```

Comment: Resumindo, é a mesma coisa que uma **constante**?

Comment: Não. Constantes têm valores literais definidos e **não podem ter valor mudado durante a execução**. Você pode definir um literal para uma variável e mudar os valores depois.

Comment: Então os literais são variáveis? Literal é o valor que eu dou para o membro, e então durante a execução o literal vira uma variável?

Comment: Quase isso. Você define um valor literal para uma variável.

Comment: Editei os exemplos @RZ-8121