# Constante é realmente útil?

Tags: variáveis, independente-de-linguagem, constantes

- Por que eu usaria uma constante em vez de uma variável?
- Além da legibilidade, há outro ganho em usar uma constante?

Não consigo perceber uma diferença que me faça usar uma constante em vez de uma variável.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Não sei se há legibilidade maior. Até há se considerar que ela indica melhor a intenção do valor ser constante. Veja mais em [O que são "Números Mágicos"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135108/101).

A constante, desde que seja constante mesmo<sup>*</sup>, tem a vantagem da proteção, qualquer tentativa de escrever nela não funcionará. Se é o que deseja, então é interessante que o compilador ajude nisto.

Note que é muito comum chamarmos *variáveis somente leitura* de constante. Se o valor é determinado em tempo execução ela não é uma constante clássica, é uma variável que não pode ter seu valor trocado, só pode ser inicializado.

Há outros contextos onde o termo constante nem sempre significa constante de verdade. Existe a constância transitória, o que parece um contrassenso pelo menos nomear esse mecanismo de constante. Então em determinado momento a variável deve manter seu valor constante, mas ainda estamos falando de uma variável.

Tem linguagem que chama de constante o que sequer é impedido de trocar o valor. Fuja.

[Imutabilidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101) é algo bom, constância é uma imutabilidade levada ao extremo. Mas abusar de imutabilidade pode ser prejudicial. Tem [padrão de projeto que usa a imutabilidade para simplificar o uso de constantes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164960/101).

Constante pode ser melhor otimizada e usar o seu valor direto em vez de ter uma [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) para o valor que toda variável tem em algum grau. Nem todas linguagens fazem isto.

Se o dado não pode mudar, por que não garantir isto e evitar acidentes? Então sempre que for a sua situação prefira constante. Inclusive pode causar menos problemas um dia ter que tornar a constante em variável, do que o inverso. Mas mesmo assim pode ter problemas se houver a presunção que aquele valor nunca mudará. Então ela é muito útil, só não é fundamental. É possível confiar em convenções, mas eu não faria isto.

---

<sup>*</sup>Constante de verdade é um valor fixo que o código tem. É um nome que usamos no código mas que é substituído sempre por um valor fixo definido já na compilação. Algumas pessoas confundem com [literal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/114475/101). Veja [Qual é a diferença entre const e readonly?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151721/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).