# Como armazenar o valor de retorno de uma função em uma váriavel local em C?

Tags: c, funções, variáveis

Criei uma função que retornava determinado valor, quando utilizo essa função na função `main` do programa, como posso fazer para armazenar o retorno dela, e por exemplo, exibir esse retorno em um `printf` na `main`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int distanciaCorrida(int inicio, int fim){
    int distancia = 0;
    distancia = fim - inicio;
    return distancia;
}

int main(){
    int kminicial, kmfinal;
    kminicial = 200000;
    kmfinal = 207349;
    distanciaCorrida(kminicial,kmfinal);
    printf("A distancia percorrida pelo carro foi de %d km",);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não é nem muito uma questão de não estar conseguindo mas sim de como fazer. mas vou colocar o código

Comment: Só fazer int dp = distanciaCorrida(kminicial,kmfinal); e depois printf("A distancia percorrida pelo carro foi de %d km", &dp);

Comment: @JoeTorres: O operador de endereço `&` está demais nessa tua expressão; vai imprimir o valor errado deste jeito.

Comment: Tem razão. & vai só no scanf não no print....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assim como você pode atribuir um valor [literal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/114473/101) na [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101), pode atribuir uma [expressão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168177/101) já que fez uma subtração, que é uma expressão. Uma expressão pode conter uma série de coisas que gerem algum resultado. Uma função gera um resultado, então é só usá-la de na atribuição da variável. Veja [explicações dos termo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163079/101)s.

Aproveitei e simplifiquei o código.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int distanciaCorrida(int inicio, int fim) {
    return fim - inicio;
}

int main() {
    int kminicial = 200000;
    int kmfinal = 207349;
    int distancia = distanciaCorrida(kminicial, kmfinal);
    printf("A distancia percorrida pelo carro foi de %d km", distancia);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/JW0QT4). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rfyhkjyn-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/Attribuition.c).

A variável `distancia` aí nem é necessária, na verdade todas elas, mas para fazer da maneira exposta e indicar como fazer se fosse algo que a variável é necessária. Poderia fazer:

```
printf("A distancia percorrida pelo carro foi de %d km", distanciaCorrida(kminicial, kmfinal));
```

A não ser em um caso de querer gerar uma abstração, é até mais simples fazer o cálculo simples direto sem criar uma função, mas entendo que seja uma questão de aprendizado. Só não aprende fazer sempre assim se não tiver necessidade.

Uma [pergunta bem parecida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44741/101).