# Validar input sem colocar em variável

Tags: python, variáveis, input

```
num = int(input("Digite um numero: "))

if num <= 10:
    print("Ok, numero registrado")
else:
    print("Numero invalido, digite outro numero menor que 10")
```

Caso o numero seja maior que 10 é pra digitar um número novamente que seja menor que 10, mas como faz isso sem registrar o número ali em `num`.

Comment: Praticamente duplicada de [Aceitar somente numéricos no input](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/244764/5878)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Complementando a resposta do Maniero...

O Python possui uma memória *temporária*, a *stack*, que é utilizada para executar o seu código. Sempre que você chamar uma função, o retorno será automaticamente armazenado na *stack*. A diferença entre armazenar o retorno em uma variável ou não é o que acontecerá depois disso.

Quando você atribui o retorno a uma variável, o interpretador do Python executará outra instrução que move o valor da *stack* para outra memória independente, referenciando a variável ao endereço deste valor nesta memória. Diferente de algumas outras linguagens, a relação variável/valor não é um para um. O interpretador irá gerar uma tabela associando várias variáveis a um determinado valor (sobre isso, você pode pesquisar sobre dados [i]mutáveis). Na internet você geralmente verá uma associação disso como variáveis sendo etiquetas e não caixas que armazenam um valor.

Vejamos o que o [disassembler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) nos mostra do código abaixo:

```
num = int(input("Digite um numero: "))

if num <= 10:
    print("Ok, numero registrado")
```

*Opcodes* executados pelo interpretador:

```
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (int)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (input)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 ('Digite um numero: ')
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             10 STORE_NAME               2 (num)

  3          12 LOAD_NAME                2 (num)
             14 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
             16 COMPARE_OP               1 (<=)
             18 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       28

  4          20 LOAD_NAME                3 (print)
             22 LOAD_CONST               2 ('Ok, numero registrado')
             24 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             26 POP_TOP
        >>   28 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
             30 RETURN_VALUE
None
```

Na sequência, ocorre-se:

1. Carrega-se o objeto de nome `int`, que será um objeto chamável;
2. Carrega-se o objeto de nome `input`, que será um objeto chamável;
3. Carrega a constante, armazenando-a na *stack*, do tipo *string*, `'Digite um numero: '`;
4. Chama-se a última função carregada, `input`, passando o topo da *stack* como parâmetro, armazenando o retorno no topo da *stack*;
5. Chama-se a última função carregada, `int`, passando o topo da *stack* como parâmetro, armazenando o retorno no topo da *stack*;
6. Armazena o valor no topo da *stack* em um local identificado por `num`;

Após isso, basicamente o interpretador acessará o valor identificado por `num`, carregará os operadores necessários e executará as instruções devidas. O que nos importa aqui são as instruções `CALL_FUNCTION` e `STORE_NAME`. Vemos a descrição de cada uma conforme a documentação:

> **[STORE_NAME(namei)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-STORE_NAME)**
>
> *Implements `name = TOS`. `namei` is the index of name in the attribute `co_names` of the code object. The compiler tries to use STORE_FAST or STORE_GLOBAL if possible.*
>
> **[CALL_FUNCTION(argc)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-CALL_FUNCTION)**
>
> *Calls a callable object with positional arguments. `argc` indicates the
>   number of positional arguments. The top of the stack contains
>   positional arguments, with the right-most argument on top. Below the
>   arguments is a callable object to call. `CALL_FUNCTION` pops all
>   arguments and the callable object off the stack, calls the callable
>   object with those arguments, and pushes the return value returned by*
>   the callable object.

**Nota:** Leia-se `TOS` como *top-of-stack* (último valor adicionado à *stack*).

Como comentado, `CALL_FUNCTION` remove do topo da *stack* a quantidade de valores a serem passados para a função que será chamada e adiciona o retorno de volta à *stack*, enquanto `STORE_NAME` define na tabela uma associação entre o nome (variável) com o valor no topo da *stack*.

Devido a essa associação com a variável e o valor, em outra memória, será possível você acessar futuramente o valor através da variável. Ela será persistente até o fim da execução do escopo da variável. Diferente de quando você não atribui à variável, pois neste caso o valor é armazenado apenas na *stack*, sendo removido ou ignorado pela próxima instrução a ser executada.

Pode não ter percebido, mas você implementou as duas formas no seu exemplo. O retorno de `int()` você atribuiu à variável `num`, mas o retorno de `input` você não armazenou em uma variável. Assim, volte ali nos *opcodes* executados pelo interpretador e veja o que aconteceu:

```
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (int)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (input)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 ('Digite um numero: ')
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             10 STORE_NAME               2 (num)
```

O primeiro `CALL_FUNCTION` será o responsável por chamar a função `input`, pois foi a última a carregar na *stack*. Perceba que não é executado um `STORE_NAME` após a chamada da função, visto que o retorno não foi atribuído a uma variável. Na verdade, o retorno foi armazenado no topo da *stack*, como de costume, porém já foi removido pela próxima instrução, a `CALL_FUNCTION` que executa a função `int`. Ou seja, o retorno de `input` é armazenado na *stack*, utilizado como parâmetro por `int` e se perde.

O mesmo acontece quando você não atribui o retorno à variável `num`:

```
if int(input("Digite um numero: ")) <= 10:
    print("Ok, numero registrado")
```

Executando os seguintes *opcodes*:

```
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (int)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (input)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 ('Digite um numero: ')
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             10 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
             12 COMPARE_OP               1 (<=)
             14 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       24

  2          16 LOAD_NAME                2 (print)
             18 LOAD_CONST               2 ('Ok, numero registrado')
             20 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             22 POP_TOP
        >>   24 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
             26 RETURN_VALUE
None
```

Perceba que ao invés de executar `STORE_NAME`, o interpretador agora executará `LOAD_CONST`, para colocar na *stack* a constante 10 e posteriormente executar o operador de comparação, `COMPARE_OP`, que é um operador binário, necessitando, assim, de dois operandos que serão os dois valores no topo da *stack*: a constante 10 e o retorno de `int`. Após isso, o retorno de `int` se perderá.

Para solicitar ao usuário enquanto ele não entrar com um valor válido, já comentei nesta outra resposta:

- [Aceitar somente numéricos no input](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/244764/5878)

Que resume-se a:

```
while True:
    try:
        numero = int(input("Informe um número menor ou igual a 10: "))
        if numero > 10:
            raise ValueError("Número não pode ser maior que 10")
    except ValueError as e:
        print("Valor inválido:", e)
    else:
        break

print(numero)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/DarlingOrdinaryMineral)</sup>

Perceba que além da verificação se o número lido é menor que 10, é também utilizado exceções, pois a função `int` lança uma exceção `ValueError` caso a entrada não possa ser convertida para inteiro. Um caso típico é quando o usuário entra com uma letra ao invés de um número. Sem capturar a exceção, seu programa iria se encerrar nessa situação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sem armazenar na variável ficaria então:

```
while True:
    try:
        if int(input("Informe um número menor ou igual a 10: ")) > 10:
            raise ValueError("Número não pode ser maior que 10")
    except ValueError as e:
        print("Valor inválido:", e)
    else:
        break

print(r'Valor válido, mas não sei qual foi ¯\_(ツ)_/¯')
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/LinedFarCarat)</sup>

Por curiosidade, esse será o *opcode* executado:

```
  1           0 SETUP_LOOP              80 (to 82)

  2     >>    2 SETUP_EXCEPT            28 (to 32)

  3           4 LOAD_NAME                0 (int)
              6 LOAD_NAME                1 (input)
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 ('Informe um número menor ou igual a 10: ')
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             14 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
             16 COMPARE_OP               4 (>)
             18 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       28

  4          20 LOAD_NAME                2 (ValueError)
             22 LOAD_CONST               2 ('Número não pode ser maior que 10')
             24 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             26 RAISE_VARARGS            1
        >>   28 POP_BLOCK
             30 JUMP_FORWARD            44 (to 76)

  5     >>   32 DUP_TOP
             34 LOAD_NAME                2 (ValueError)
             36 COMPARE_OP              10 (exception match)
             38 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       74
             40 POP_TOP
             42 STORE_NAME               3 (e)
             44 POP_TOP
             46 SETUP_FINALLY           16 (to 64)

  6          48 LOAD_NAME                4 (print)
             50 LOAD_CONST               3 ('Valor inválido:')
             52 LOAD_NAME                3 (e)
             54 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             56 POP_TOP
             58 POP_BLOCK
             60 POP_EXCEPT
             62 LOAD_CONST               4 (None)
        >>   64 LOAD_CONST               4 (None)
             66 STORE_NAME               3 (e)
             68 DELETE_NAME              3 (e)
             70 END_FINALLY
             72 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            2
        >>   74 END_FINALLY

  8     >>   76 BREAK_LOOP
             78 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            2
             80 POP_BLOCK

 10     >>   82 LOAD_NAME                4 (print)
             84 LOAD_CONST               5 ('Valor válido, mas não sei qual foi ¯\_(ツ)_/¯')
             86 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             88 POP_TOP
             90 LOAD_CONST               4 (None)
             92 RETURN_VALUE
None
```

Answer (score 9):

```
if int(input("Digite um numero: ")) <= 10:
    print("Ok, numero registrado")
else:
   print("Numero invalido, digite outro numero menor que 10")
```

[Variáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) são locais de armazenamento de valores, só isso. Você não precisa delas quando não usa o valor mais de uma vez. Mesmo quando precisa em tese pode obter o valor todas as vezes calculando de novo (tem casos que isto pode ser problemático), e tem casos que a API usada exige usar um variável. Neste caso o número só é usado uma vez e a variável é totalmente desnecessária. Então onde está o uso da variável você coloca a expressão que tinha guardado na variável e aí está usando o valor diretamente sem guardar em alguma variável.

Variáveis não são mágicas, não possuem poderes especiais, ela é só o que foi descrito acima. Onde aceita uma variável aceita uma [expressão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168177/101) ou um [literal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/114473/101).

Códigos são como um monte de peças de Lego, o que importa é dar o encaixe, dá para usar a criatividade desde que faça sentido encaixar aquilo. O compilador trata o que pode e o que não pode. Costumo usar a frase em minhas palestras:

[image: Enquanto você não souber o que cada caractere do seu código faz, até mesmo o espaço em branco, você ainda não sabe programar.]

Procure organizar bem a escrita dos seus código, especialmente em Python onde o espaço é significativo.

Já para repetir tem que encapsular este código em um laço. Tem como fazer a verificação na condição do laço, e aí precisará da variável, ou precisa fazer um laço infinito e aí tem que quebrar a execução:

```
while(True):
    if int(input("Digite um numero: ")) <= 10:
        print("Ok, numero registrado")
        break
    else:
       print("Numero invalido, digite outro numero menor que 10")
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/8vXj7o). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/atflpqwr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/LoopDataEntry.py).

Comment: Nossa, valeu :D

Answer (score -4):

Pelo que eu pude entender da sua pergunta é que: enquanto o número for maior que 10, repetir a instrução de input até o número ser menor ou igual a 10. Recomendo estudar a estruturá de loop do Python.

```
while(True):
    if int(input("Digite um numero: ")) <= 10:
        print("Ok, numero registrado")
        break;
    else:
        print("Numero invalido, digite outro numero menor que 10")
```

Comment: Sim sim, era isso tambem, e valeu pela recomendaçao, ainda to saindo e if e else essas coisas...

Comment: Já que a intenção é melhorar a resposta, aproveita e corrige a indentação xD