# O que são tipos literais em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Eu já vi várias vezes os termos na programação de tipos literais, mas eu não sei o que é isso, por exemplo, string literal, números literais, objetos literais e etc. O que é isso? Há alguma diferença para um tipo normal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Literais são exatamente escrever o valor, por exemplo isto seria um "Array literal":

```
var x = [ "a", "b", "c" ];
```

Isto já não é:

```
var x = new Array();

x.push("a");
x.push("b");
x.push("c");
```

"Literal" é um valor que você escreve literalmente no seu script, pode ser atribuindo a uma variável, ou passando com argumento de uma função, ou até escrever **solto** no seu script, sem atribuir ou setar nada, o que importa é que se escreve exatamente o que será o valor (claro que tendo certas situações como "escapes" e outros detalhes).

### Booleano Literal

É escrever `true` e `false` diretamente no script atribuindo a sua variável ou definindo em algum lugar:

```
var x = true;
```

Aqui `x` tem atribuído um valor não literal, (o valor ainda é `true`):

```
var x = !!1;
```

Se o retorno de uma função ou uma condição diretamente atribuída ocasionar true ou false não será literal, por exemplo:

```
 var x = condicao1 || condicao2;
```

Isto também não é:

```
 var x = foo();

 function foo() {
    return condicao1 || condicao2;
 }
```

### Regex Literal

Em regex a maioria já conhece e acaba usando o literal mesmo que seria como os exemplos:

```
/foo/
/foo/g
/foo|bar/gi
```

Mas existe o "não literal", que seria útil para customizar dinamicamente seu regex:

```
new Regex("foo")
new Regex("foo", "g")
new Regex("foo", "gi")
```

Estes valores são equivalentes aos literais, mas você poderia ajustar via valores e variáveis

### Objeto literal

O objeto literal é escrito entre `{...}`, um objeto literal pode conter

### String literal

As strings literais podem ser escritas:

```
'foo'
"bar"
'foo \n bar'
"baz' bar"
"baz\" bar"
```

Note que quebras de linha usasse o `\n`, e tem vários "escapes" como `\0`, `\t`, etc, mas escreve-los não deixara de ser literal, pois você está escrevendo o valor de certa forma, JavaScript tinha (não padronizado) meio de quebrar linhas dentro script (não do valor) usando o `\`, assim:

```
var x = 'foo\
bar\
baz';
```

Seria um meio de quebrar linhas longas, mas a partir do ES6 passamos a ter os **Template literais** (antes chamado de "Template strings")

```
`foo bar`

`foo
bar`

var a = 1, b = 2;

`foo ${a + b} bar`

`foo ${a * b} bar`
```

Note que foi possível quebrar linhas "no valor" no segundo exemplo.

No terceiro e quarto exemplo você pode notar as expressões dentro de `${...}`, ter expressões não muda o fato do template ser literal, porque literal é o "template" neste caso.

---

Tem algumas coisas sobre ES6 que eu preciso adicionar, como arrays não "conter" de todos itens, exemplo `[ "a", , "c"]`, neste caso o índice 1 retornaria `undefined`, o array continua sendo literal é claro, com o tempo vou adicionando estes detalhes é apenas uma respostas inicial.

Comment: Eu acho que eu entendi o que é valores literais, só para confirmar meu entendimento no assunto, por exemplo, objetos literais, strings literais e etc são valores que são escritos claramente como, por exemplo, `'Olá', 25, {n1: 30}` e etc? e já valores não literais são valores que são escritos obscuramente como, por exemplo, `10 < 10, typeof n1`, etc?

Comment: @felipecardozo basicamente isso mesmo, por isso citei os exemplos, em literais você escreve exatamente o que vai ser, qualquer outra coisa não ;)

Comment: Valeu amigo, agora tudo faz sentido, obrigado :)

Comment: @felipecardozo não, não é isso. Pelo menos não em um dos exemplos que deu.. No código `10 < 10` por exemplo tem 2 literais, iguais por sinal que formam uma expressão, mas o código inteiro não é um literal. Literal é uma forma de expressão. Por isso eu coloquei na minha resposta um um *link*  que explica corretamente como é um literal, não coloquei aqui porque a pergunta seria duplicata e fechada. Literal é uma das coisas mais simples que existe para entender, leia lá.

Comment: Valeu, @Maniero, me equivoquei nesse exemplo citado.

Answer (score 4):

Literais não são tipos, esse termo está errado. Os literais possuem um tipo, é diferente. Então não é que não tem diferença para um "tipo normal", não há relação, e não existe tipo normal, tipo é tipo. Se leu o termo dessa forma da pergunta, fuja do material.

Então o mais correto é ter um literal de `string`, ou literal de número, ou literal de objeto. Provavelmente o termo foi usado dessa forma por má tradução.

Valores possuem tipos. Um literal é um valor. Em JavaScript [variáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) não possuem tipos, apenas valores. Um literal é só uma forma de expressar um valor no código.

[O que é um literal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/114473/101) já foi bem respondido, não tem porque responder novamente essa parte.

O literal então é um `"texto aqui"` ou é um `12` ou ainda um `{ x : 1, y : 2 }` para citar os três que estão na pergunta. Só isso, qualquer outra parte do código não é o literal.

Answer (score 2):

> Fonte e para mais detalhes: [MDN-Javascript, Sintaxe e tipos](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals)

Literais em Javascript são valores fixados, não variáveis, que **literalmente** são inseridos em seu script.
Os literais em Javascript são:

- Array literal
- Literais lógicos
- Literais de ponto flutuante
- Inteiros literais
- Objeto literal
- String literal

**Array literal**

Um array literal é uma lista de zero ou mais expressões, onde cada uma delas representam um elemento do array, inseridas entre colchetes (`[]`):

```
var coffees = ["French Roast", "Colombian", "Kona"];
```

Você não precisa especificar todos os elementos em um array literal. Se você colocar duas vírgulas em uma linha, o array é criado com undefined para os elementos não especificados.

```
var fish = ["Lion", , "Angel"];
```

**Literais lógicos**

O tipo lógicos tem dois valores literais: `true` e `false`.

```
var x = false;
```

**Inteiros literais**

Inteiros podem ser expressos em decimal (base 10), hexadecimal (base 16), octal (base 8) e binário (base 2).

- Decimal inteiro literal consiste em uma sequência de dígitos sem um
  `0` a esquerda.
- `0` a esquerda em um inteiro literal indica que ele está em formato
  octal.Octal pode incluir somente os dígitos 0-7.
- 0x (ou 0X) indica um hexadecimal. Inteiros hexadecimais podem
  incluir dígitos (0-9) e as letras a-f e A-F.
- 0b (ou 0B) indica um binário. Inteiros binário podem incluir apenas
  os dígitos 0 e 1.

Alguns exemplos de inteiros literal são:

```
0, 117, -345 (decimal, base 10)
015, 0001,  -077 (octal, base 8) 
0x1123, 0x00111,  -0xF1A7 (hexadecimal, "hex" or base 16)
0b11, 0b0011, -0b11 (binário, base 2)
```

**Literais de ponto flutuante**

Possuem a seguinte sintaxe:

[(+|-)][digitos][.digitos][(E|e)[(+|-)]digitos]

Por exemplo:

```
3.1415926
-.123456789
-3.1E+12
.1e-23
```

**Objeto literal**
Um objeto literal é uma lista de zero ou mais pares de nomes de propriedades e valores associados de um objeto, colocado entre chaves (`{}`)

```
var carro = { carros: {a: "Saab", "b": "Jeep"}, 7: "Mazda" };
```