# Função retornando outra função

Tags: python, funções

Como a segunda função está retornando a função `f`?

E para onde está sendo retornado a função `f` já que, quando eu dou `print` na variável, o valor retornado é 'oi' e 'none'?

```
def f(var):
    print(var)
    
def funcao():
    return f

variavel = funcao()('OI')
```

Retorno:

```
OI
None
```

[image: função no python retornando outra função]

Comment: Eu queria saber pra onde que tá sendo retornado a função f e qual o motivo de colocar o segundo parêntese com valor ('oi') porque se eu da um print na variavel o valor vai ser none!

Comment: Se fosse `x = funcao()`, qual seria o valor de `x`?

Comment: Sem querer, quase que consegue implementar um dispositivo mais sofisticado da linguagem onde muita gente tem dificuldade em entender o funcionamento.

Comment: O valor de x seria none

Answer (score 3):

Ok, a confusão é com a sintaxe unificada. Muita gente não entende bem a sintaxe da linguagem, seja ela qual for. É importante entender tudo o que está acontecendo e saber o que cada caractere faz no código, o que está acontecendo ali, entender os conceitos, e todas interconexões de cada mecanismo existente na linguagem. Eu falo isso em minhas palestras e até posto aqui, mas as pessoas não percebem o quanto isso é importante para programar bem:

[image: Enquanto você não souber o que cada caractere do seu código faz, até mesmo o espaço em branco, você ainda não sabe programar.]

Sabe [O que é uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101)

Sabe [O que é um literal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/114473/101)

Então quando `funcao()` é chamada ela retorna o valor contido no identificador chamado `f`. Acontece que esse identificado tem como valor uma função, descrita logo acima. Então é como se fosse uma variável (tecnicamente é uma constante, ainda que Python não tenha esse conceito para uso de outras formas). Quando o retorno é feito você pode usar esse valor em algum lugar. Uma das coisas que pode fazer é armazenar em uma variável. Mas não precisa fazer isso, você pode usar logo ali mesmo na expressão que está usando, você usa de forma *inline*.

Então vamos pensar em um código um pouco diferente:

```
def funcao():
    return 1
variavel = funcao() + 2
print variavel
```

Consegue perceber oque ocorre aí? Depois do retorno do valor é como se o código fosse assim:

```
variavel = 1 + 2
print variavel
```

è pura matemática, substituímos algo que previamente não tínhamos conhecimento do valor, portanto era uma variável ou constante, por uma valor conhecido, e conforme vamos fazendo isso conseguimos chegar a um resultado. No caso `funcao()` é o que não sabíamos o valor e que foi substituído por algo conhecido depois que a função foi chamada retornando o valor.

Você conseguem entender isto?

```
def f(var):
    print(var)
def funcao():
    return f
variavel = funcao()
variavel('OI')
```

O que está sendo guardado em `variavel`? É uma função chamada `f`, certo? Portanto agora variável `tem como valor uma função que eu posso chamá-la.

Então fazendo a substituição da função pelo seu retorno seria assim:

```
def f(var):
    print(var)
variavel = f
variavel('OI')
```

E para chamar uma função sempre uso os parênteses logo depois do identificador que nomeio a função, podendo passar argumentos ou não, dependendo da função. Nesse caso o que eu tenho de função está guardado na variável com o identificador `variavel` e assim logo depois chamei essa função com esse identificador passando um argumento dentro dos parênteses.

Ora, porque ei preciso guardar em uma variável algo que eu só quero o resultado. Se não sabia, agora lendo o *link* acima deve saber que uma variável é um nome para um local de armazenamento, e no seu código não precisa armazenar nada,, só precisa pegar o valor e usar.

Aí voltamos para o exemplo inicial da resposta onde você recebe um valor retornado pela função e já o uso imediatamente. Em vez de usar o operador de adição `+` como usei lá, agora está usando o operador de chamada de função `()`, ou como foi usado agora passando argumento `('OI')`, portanto o literal `'OI'` é como se fosse o `2` do meu primeiro exemplo.

Note que não há nada de especial no conceito. Apenas teve um intersecção de mecanismos diferentes. Provavelmente já sabia chamar uma função e usar em uma expressão. Provavelmente já sabia usa ruma função anônima, mas por alguma razão achava que não podia usar os dois juntos igual faz com um valor numérico ou de outra forma. È uma questão linear, se pensar bem nem faria sentido ser diferente, se funciona de um jeito porque impediria funcionar de outro? Até pode existir algum motivo, mas neste caso não tem.

Então substituindo a função pelo seu retorno no seu código seria:

```
def f(var):
    print(var)
variavel = f('OI')
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Function/Anonymous.py).

nesse caso nem faz sentido existir a variável `variavel` porque ela armazena um valor nulo já que ela sequer tem um `return`.

Comment: Posso usar essa imagem?

Comment: Pode, claro....

Comment: Não entendi a parte da "variavel = f" e "variavel('oi')". Será que depois que eu retorno a função f ,a variavel passar ser uma função e depois que eu chamo a variavel e passo um valor "oi", por exemplo, este valor vai para a função f que eu defini lá em cima e mostra o valor na tela?

Comment: Exatamente isso.

Comment: E como funciona esse sem variavel "funcao()('Oi')" ?

Comment: Está explicado na resposta.

Comment: Cara, eu acho que entendi sim! quando a variavel receber o retorno da função f, a variavel passa ser uma função, ou seja, "variavel = funcao()" é a mesma coisa que "variavel = f", então variavel=f equivale a uma função só, que eu posso chamar ela dessa forma " variavel('Oi')", ou assim: varivel = funcao()('OI'). Será que meu pensamento está correto?

Comment: Sim, exato.....

Comment: Obrigado amigo! você é muito bom.

Comment: @FelipeSoares dê uma olhada no [tour] como aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema.

Comment: Já aceitei. TMJ!

Comment: Não aceitou, quando o fizer aparecerá o sinal verde logo abaixo dos votos., aí na esquerda da resposta.

Answer (score 2):

> alguém poderia me explicar como a segunda funcao está retornando a funcao f?

A função `funcao` está retornando `f`, que é uma função. Quando você faz:

```py
variavel = funcao()("OI")
print(variavel)
```

é a mesma coisa que:

```py
retorno = funcao()
variavel = retorno("OI")

print(variavel)
```

> [...] e para onde está sendo retornado a função f já que quando eu dou print na variavel o valor retornado é 'oi' e 'none'.

A função `f` não retorna nada. Você está apenas usando `print` dentro dela. Por esse motivo ela retorna `None`.